# Como verificar se parte de uma string esta contida em uma lista Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou escrevendo um script Python3, com o objetivo de colocar um filtro para impedir que o usuário passe uma string contendo uma palavra ofensiva ou impropria.

Sendo assim criei uma lista contendo as palavras nas quais quero colocar esse filtro e após tratei elas com os operadores **not in** e **in** sendo que quando o a condição **not in** for atendida quero continuar a execução do script e quando a condição **in** for atendida quero retornar a execução alertando o usuário que a string passada por ele contem uma palavra ofensiva

Eu até consegui fazer com que o script funcione, porém somente quando a string passada seja == ao valor contido na lista.

Queria fazer esse filtro de uma forma mais completa analisando todo o texto e caso uma parte da string contenha o valor contido na lista, queria que o script também executasse o bloco de código da instrução **in**

Abaixo estou colocando o script:

class TextoOfencivo():

```
     def verifica():

            texto = input('Digite um texto: ').strip()

            texto_formatado = texto.upper()

            my_list = [
            "AAA", "BBB"
            ]

            iniciar = None
            while(iniciar == None):

                    if(texto_formatado not in my_list):
                            print('\n' * 1)
                            print('Bem Vindo')
                            print('\n' * 1)
                            ###### CONTINUA O SCRIPT #####
                            break

                    elif(texto_formatado  in list(my_list)):
                            print('\n' * 1)
                            print('O texto informado contem uma 
                            palavra ofensiva\nRetornando a Execução')
                            print('\n' * 1)
                            ###### RETORNA A EXECUÇÂO ANTERIOR ######
                            texto = None
                            return TextoOfencivo.verifica()
```

TextoOfencivo.verifica()

Alguém pode me ajudar ?
Agradeço desde já!!!

Atenciosamente,
Michael de Mattos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegando o código do JeanExtreme, fiz uma pequena mudança, pois quando eu fui testar, o código finalizava quando digitava a palavra da lista pela segunda vez:

```
def verifica(texto, palavrasProibidas):

    for palavra in palavrasProibidas:
        if palavra.lower() in texto.lower():
            return True
    return False

#(aqui eu pedi para me retornar True caso encontre a palavra da lista)

palavrasProibidas = ["catapimbas"]
texto = input("Digite o texto: ")

while verifica(texto, palavrasProibidas):
    texto = input("Digite outro texto: ")
#(aqui no lugar de "for", estou chamando um "while" para que, enquanto a palavra da lista estiver sendo digitada, o código vai me pedir para digitar outro texto)
else:
    print("O resultado não contém palavras ofensivas")
```

Também fico agradecido ao Jean por me ajudar a achar o caminho para executar essa função.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você verificar com o operador `in` se as strings dentro da lista então dentro de seu texto, percorrendo a lista com um `for` loop e utilizando o método `lower()` para que não haja diferenças entre maiúsculos e minúsculos. Veja esse exemplo que eu fiz:

```
def verifica(texto, palavrasProibidas):

    for palavra in palavrasProibidas:
        if palavra.lower() in texto.lower():
            return False
    return True


palavrasProibidas = ["c05n0","v4g4bund0","@rr0mbad0","v1@do"]
texto = input("Digite o texto: ")


if verifica(texto, palavrasProibidas):
    print("O texto não possui palavras ofensivas")

else:
    print("O texto possui palavras ofensivas.")
```

Talvez você não saiba disso, mas o operador `in` pode ser usado em qualquer objeto que possua o método `__contains__`, como strings, listas, tuplas, dicionários e outros, para verificar se um elemento está presente nele.

O que você fazia era verificar se a string bruta estava dentro da lista (`str in list`), quando você deveria verificar se alguma string da lista estava dentro do texto com uma *substring* (`str in str`).

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Resolveu meu problema e a explicação foi nota 10.